# Meka api i want to integrate Meka in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class Evaluate {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        //load datasets
        DataSource source = new DataSource("F:/data/solar_flare.arff");
        Instances dataset = source.getDataSet();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:/data/solar_flare.arff"));
        Instances training = new Instances(reader);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:/data/solar_flare.arff"));
        Instances testing = new Instances(reader);
        J48 jjjj = new J48();
        MultilabelClassifier PS = new PS();
        PS.setClassifier(jjjj);
        PS.setOptions(Utils.splitOptions("-threshold PCut1 -verbosity 3"));

        PS.buildClassifier(training);
        Evaluation ecal = new Evaluation(training);
        ecal.evaluateModel(PS, testing);

        dataset.setClassIndex(dataset.numAttributes()-1);
        J48 tree = new J48();
        tree.buildClassifier(dataset);
        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(dataset);  
        Random rand = new Random(1);
        int folds = 10;
        DataSource source1 = new DataSource("F:/data/solar_flare.arff");
        Instances testDataset = source1.getDataSet();
        testDataset.setClassIndex(testDataset.numAttributes()-1);
        eval.crossValidateModel(tree, testDataset, folds, rand);
        System.out.println(eval.toMatrixString("=== Confusion Matrix ===\n"));

    }
}
```

This my Code its give error back

This is error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   weka.core.Attribute.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)V   at
>   meka.core.PSUtils.PSTransformation(PSUtils.java:416)  at
>   meka.classifiers.multilabel.PS.buildClassifier(PS.java:225)"  at
>   Evaluate.main(Evaluate.java:57)

Comment: This is a typical error when you are using a library with a version that does not correspond to what you expect. Can you make sure the weka.core.Attribute exists in your version with the specified method?

Comment: Thank u for Comment  Guy Bouallet...but i will check everything ..weka.jar and also meka.jar everything is perfects but still i get error...plz help me..

Comment: i want to integrate MEKA pruned sets method in Java ..if u have another code for this plz send to me.........

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical error when you are using a library with a version that does not correspond to what you expect. You have to make sure the weka.core.Attribute exists in your version with the specified method.

Comment: Thank u for Comment Guy Bouallet...but i will check everything ..weka.jar and also meka.jar everything is perfects but still i get error...plz help me.
i want to integrate MEKA pruned sets method in Java ..if u have another code for this plz send to me.......

Comment: What version do you have and how did you declare it in your project?

Comment: and i have JDK 1.7 and JRE 1.8